# индекс списка вне допустимого диапазона

Tags: python, pandas, arcgis

Имеется ссылка `R:\TEST\pol.xlsx\'1$`
Нужно разбить ее

```
df=('R:\TEST\pol.xlsx\'1$')
df.split('\'')
```

и вставить в

```
fcc=df.split('\'')
df_1=pd.read_excel(fcc[0],fcc[1])
```

Будет ли так работать ? на данный момент у меня появляется ошибка
`IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Для приведенной строки оно работает. Значит среди прилетающих строк бывают и без `'`.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME в том то и дело строка одна

Comment: У меня тоже работает. Наверняка проблема в каком-то не показанном нам коде

Comment: может, это [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) возвращает IndexError: list index out of range?

Comment: а что вы собственно хотели указать - `1$` - это у вас Excel лист так называется??

Comment: @MaxU лист называется 1 но в  ссылке почему то указан как 1$

Comment: Изменяя суть вопроса, на который вам уже дали ответ(ы), вы тем самым инвалидируете эти ответы

Answer (score 2):

Указанная в вопросе ошибка возникнет в том случае если в строке отсутствует знак одиночной кавычки.

Воспроизведение:

```
In [137]: df=('R:\TEST\pol.xlsx')

In [138]: fcc=df.split('\'')

In [139]: fcc[1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-139-2f7ba60166ae> in <module>
----> 1 fcc[1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Если исходить из того что в этом случае нужно читать первый лист в Excel, то лучше сделать так:

```
df_1 = pd.read_excel(*fcc)
```

Это будет работать и в том случае когда в `fcc` всего один элемент и в том когда их два.

Comment: прописал теперь появляется вот такая ошибка ``IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: u'R:\\TEST\\pol.xlsx\\'``

Comment: @Grechkin26, имя файла не может оканчиваться на обратный слеш

Comment: откуда он там появляется если мы разбиваем ``R:\TEST\pol.xlsx\'1$`` и должно получится ``R:\TEST\pol.xlsx`` и ``'1$` `` или я что то не так понимаю

Comment: @Grechkin26, очевидно в строке не было символа одиночной кавычки и она, строка, заканчивается на обратный слеш. Вы можете легко увидеть содержимое строки, добавив перед `df.split('\'')` вывод строки на печать...